# What is this VS2015 code marker?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Here are some code editor markers in Visual Studio 2015:

[image: VS2015 code icons]

The second one is a bookmark and the third is a debugger breakpoint.

What's the first one?

Also, does anyone know of a list of these and other markers?

Answer (score 3):

*sigh*

After wondering about this for several days, I just realized what it was.

If you do a "Find All", you're provided with a list of search hits. You can select an item from that list. That marker is for the line matching your currently selected search results item.

Comment: indeed. I had that same question once some years ago.

Comment: In prior versions of VS, you could use Find-in-files to "Mark all Occurrences" of a find result with these icons.